# SC Truffle Testing: Domain Object Returned?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, ganache

Working through some tests in Truffle to become more acquainted with the environment but am running into an issue.

**What I am trying to do**

Test a smart contract with, among others, the following functions:

```
// Register an item using an identifier type (no., PID, barcode, etc.), the actual identifier/code, and a description
function registerItem(string memory _identifier, string memory _code, string memory _description) public {
    // Make sure the item does not already exists/is not already registered
    require(!itemExists[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_identifier,_code))]);
    // Create an Item struct in memory that stores the item data
    Item memory newItem;
    newItem.identifier = _identifier;
    newItem.code = _code;
    newItem.description = _description;
    // Map hash of item details to true/bring item into existence
    itemExists[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_identifier,_code))] = true;
    // Increment tokenCounter;
    tokenCounter ++;
    // Set unique tokenId using tokenCounter
    uint256 tokenId = tokenCounter;
    // Map the tokenId to the item
    tokenIdtoItem[tokenId] = newItem;
    // Mint the token using ERC721 mint method, which checks if the token is already owned and if not sets it to the new owner
    ERC721Token.mint(tokenId);
    //Emit event
    emit ItemRegistered(tokenId, _identifier, _code);
}

// Get item details by providing a tokenId
function getItemByToken(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (string memory identifier, string memory code, string memory description) {
    Item memory returnItem = tokenIdtoItem[_tokenId];
    return(returnItem.identifier,returnItem.code,returnItem.description);
}
```

I am testing it with:

```
const assetTracker = artifacts.require("AssetTracker");

contract("AssetTracker contract test", async accounts => {
  it("should register an item", async () => {
    let instance = await assetTracker.deployed();
    await instance.registerItem("Barcode", "13456-fgs", "This is the first dummy item.", { from: accounts[0]});
    assert.equal(instance.getItemByToken(1), ["Barcode", "13456-fgs", "This is the first dummy item."]);
    // assert.equal(instance.ownerOf(1), accounts[0], "token is not owned by any or the correct user");
  });

});
```

**What I am getting when testing in Truffle console on a ganache client:**

```
 Contract: AssetTracker contract test
    1) should register an item

    Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------

    Transfer(_from: <indexed>, _to: <indexed>, _tokenId: <indexed>)
    ItemRegistered(_tokenId: <indexed>, _identifier: <indexed>, _code: <indexed>)

    ---------------------------


  0 passing (237ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: AssetTracker contract test
       should register an item:
     AssertionError: expected { domain:
   { domain: null,
     _events:
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [],
     _errorHandler: [Function],
     enter: [Function],
     exit: [Function],
     add: [Function],
     remove: [Function],
     run: [Function],
     intercept: [Function],
     bind: [Function],
     setMaxListeners: [Function: setMaxListeners],
     getMaxListeners: [Function: getMaxListeners],
     emit: [Function],
     addListener: [Function: addListener],
     on: [Function: addListener],
     prependListener: [Function: prependListener],
     once: [Function: once],
     prependOnceListener: [Function: prependOnceListener],
     removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
     off: [Function: removeListener],
     removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners],
     listeners: [Function: listeners],
     rawListeners: [Function: rawListeners],
     listenerCount: [Function: listenerCount],
     eventNames: [Function: eventNames] } } to equal [ Array(3) ]
      at Context.it (test\assettracker.js:7:12)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)



1
```

Any ideas on what is happening? When I run the commands lose in the console (e.g. migrating, connecting to contract, executing the functions) everything works well.

Thanks in advance. Take care!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be calling the contract method with await as given below.

```
const assetTracker = artifacts.require("AssetTracker");

contract("AssetTracker contract test", async accounts => {
  it("should register an item", async () => {
    let instance = await assetTracker.deployed();
    await instance.registerItem("Barcode", "13456-fgs", "This is the first dummy item.", { from: accounts[0]});
    assert.equal(await instance.getItemByToken(1), ["Barcode", "13456-fgs", "This is the first dummy item."]);
    // assert.equal(instance.ownerOf(1), accounts[0], "token is not owned by any or the correct user");
  });

});
```

You should also consider using the beforeEach methods to reconstruct the instance without retaining the state across various test methods.

```
let instance;
beforeEach('setup contract instance for each test case execution', async () => {
    instance = await assetTracker.new();
});
```

and use as given below,

```
it("should register an item", async () => {
    await instance.registerItem("Barcode", "13456-fgs", "This is the first dummy item.", { from: accounts[0]});
    assert.equal(await instance.getItemByToken(1), ["Barcode", "13456-fgs", "This is the first dummy item."]);
    // assert.equal(instance.ownerOf(1), accounts[0], "token is not owned by any or the correct user");
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Totally forgot to add the await inside the assert function. Thanks for pointing it out! Happy holidays!

Comment: Happy Holidays and wish you a very happy and prosperous New Year 2019

Comment: Same to you! Have a great 2019!